# Is it possible to set different environment variables per executor in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I currently have a functioning CI pipeline with a single node (the master) and a single executor. The builds and test suite themselves run as a script on the master node, but delegates all the actual work to a Docker container that runs the actual application.

This application is built on a framework that is *very* slow and expensive to start up, so I have the application running permanently in a Docker container. The Jenkinsfile handles updating the application at runtime (which is relatively fast) and running the test suite.

In theory, everything I need to expand my setup to multiple Docker containers so that test runs for multiple branches can run in parallel is to:

- Duplicate the application Docker container
- Increase the number of executors on the master node
- Set the environment variable "DOCKER_CONTAINER" for each executor to point to the different Docker containers

However, after searching the Jenkins control panel to the best of my abilities, I can't find any controls for executors other then "Number of executors". I can't find any per-executor settings.

Are there any controls to set environment variables per-executor that I have missed? If not are there any plugins to achieve this? Or will I have to embed my environment variables in my Jenkinsfile and pick between them using `$EXECUTOR_NUMBER`? (I would much rather keep that kind of environment specific stuff in Jenkins.)

Comment: Why not connect your application to the Jenkins as an agent, and then run the tests directly on the application agent - then when adding other containers they will be added as new agents and you can use the label mechanism for distributing jobs.

Comment: @NoamHelmer The Docker host is a separate server from the Jenkins server. The Jenkins server has access to the Docker host and the Git repository, but the Docker host doesn't have direct access to the Git repository. This could probably have been fixed in time, but corporate environments are slow and I was in a hurry. (This is not a new pipeline.) At this point it would be a big refactor and involve downtime. That doesn't seem worth it when all I'm currently missing to have working parallel test runs is separate environment variables for each executor.

Comment: then you will have to mange the state of application by yourself, or within the jenkins file or as an external configuration file. Either way better not relay on the executer number itself bath rather on the actual containers.

Comment: @NoamHelmer But then how do I decide which container to use, if not relying on the executor number? What I've currently done is spin up one container for each executor, naming them `test-pipeline-<application-name>-0/1/2/3/...`, then in my Jenkinsfile I set the environment variable `DOCKER_CONTAINER="test-pipeline-<application-name>-$EXECUTOR_NUMBER"`. That should guarantee that no two executors try to run tests on the same Docker container. It seems to be working so far. Do you see any issues with this?

Comment: no issues should work fine, just a bit wired as your environments are paired to executers.